# How do I associate the previous value in a php function?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Ok this is sort of hard to explain but basically i wrote a PHP function that prints the a tags but needs some logic. Here is what i have so far

```
function print_a($element_name, $completed_system, $category_name){
    // hw_bottom
    // hw_top
    // hw_center
    $elements = array("hardware", "software", "payment", "service", "optional");
    $last_category = last_category($completed_system);
    if($last_category == $category_name){
        echo "<a class=\"{$element_name} hw_center lf\"></a>";
    }else{
        echo "<a class=\"{$element_name} hw_bottom lf\"></a>";
    }
}
```

and here is how i call it

```
print_a("hw-tab", $completed_system, 'hardware');
print_a("sw-tab", $completed_system, 'software');
print_a("pp-tab", $completed_system, 'payment');
print_a("serv-tab", $completed_system, 'service');
print_a("ou-tab", $completed_system, 'optional');
```

all seems ok but my logic is a bit off ...basically what i need is that i print either one of the three classes hw_bottom, hw_center, or hw_top and the way my logic is working out now is that if the if condition is met i print hw_center ...thats correct ...what i need though is that if the if condition matches on anything after the hardware i need to turn all the previous to hw_top so for example:

if the if condition matched on payment then this is what i need

```
            <a class="hw-tab hw_top lf"></a>
            <a class="sw-tab hw_top lf"></a>
            <a class="pp-tab hw_center lf"></a>
            <a class="serv-tab hw_bottom lf"></a>
            <a class="ou-tab hw_bottom lf"></a>
```

As you can see all the ones after payment are hw_bottom and all the ones before are hw_top and it is hw_center....i know this is hard to explain...if anyone needs more info let ms know

**UPDATE**

HERE is the solution i came up with after reviewing all the answers

```
function print_a($completed_system){
  $topClass = true;
  $elements = array("hw-tab" => "hardware", "sw-tab" => "software", "pp-tab" => "payment", "serv-tab" => "service", "ou-tab" => "optional");
    $last_category = last_category($completed_system);
  foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
        if($last_category == $element){
        echo "<a class=\"{$key} hw_center lf\"></a>";
        $topClass = false;
    } else { 
        if ($topClass) {
            echo "<a class=\"{$key} hw_top lf\"></a>";
        } else {
            echo "<a class=\"{$key} hw_bottom lf\"></a>";
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is my $completed_systems array http://pastie.org/2810072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code can help you (if I understand question):

```
<?php
$topClass = true;

$elements = array("hardware", "software", "payment", "service", "optional");
foreach ($elements as $index => $element) {
    if (floor(count($elements) / 2) == $index) {
        echo "<a class=\"{$element} hw_center lf\"></a>";
        $topClass = false;
    } else { 
        if ($topClass) {
            echo "<a class=\"{$element} hw_top lf\"></a>";
        } else {
            echo "<a class=\"{$element} hw_bottom lf\"></a>";
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Update after your explain what you need.

Comment: thanks....i will update my answer to show you what i went with...your answer heled out ....thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand what you're trying to do but can't you simply let the function return true/false if the requirement is met and then add it as another parameter to the next function call.

The problem would be that only the only the item directly after the one where the condition evaluates to true will be affected. You solve this by simply using or:

```
$myBool = false;
$myBool = $myBool || print_a("hw-tab", $completed_system, 'hardware', $myBool);
etc..
```

and then if $myBool is true you'll print hw_bottom and if false you'll print hw_top and the time were the function change the state between true and false you print hw_center.